# grid does not refresh

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

This is the code of the init of the form

```
if !used if !used ("supplier_temp")
   SELECT supplier
     afields(structure)
        CREATE cursor supplier_temp from array structure
else
     SELECT supplier_temp
         for re = 1 to reccount()
           SELECT supplier_temp
           go re
           _id = supplier_temp.id
           _name = supplier_temp.name
           _dir = supplier_temp.dir
           _cel = supplier_temp.cellphon
           _em = supplier_temp.email
            scan
           update provider set name=_name, address=_dir, cell=_cel, email = _em where control = 1 and id = _id
            end scan
         end for
    delete all
 endif
     SELECT supplier_temp
       APPEND FROM supplier for dispatched = 1
       GO TOP
       Thisform.Suppliers.RecordSource = "supplier_temp"
       Thisform.Suppliers.column1.ControlSource = "supplier_temp.name"
       Thisform.Proveedores.column2.ControlSource = "supplier_temp.direntre"
       Thisform.Proveedores.column3.ControlSource = "provider_temp.cellphon"
       Thisform.Suppliers.column4.ControlSource = "supplier_temp.email"
```

This is the code for the process button

```
If thisform.Proveedores.Column1.Check2.Value = 1
   thisform.Preclientes.column1.Check2.valid
    select supplier_temp
    go top
   replace supplier_temp.control with 2
    locate for supplier_temp.control = 2
      REPLACE supplier.control WITH supplier_temp.control for supplier.id = supplier_temp.id IN  supplier
    Thisform.Suppliers.refresh
    thisform.Suppliers.setfocus()
    thisform.refresh
endif
```

This is the code for the reject button

```
If thisform.Suppliers.Column1.Check2.Value = 1
  if !empty(suppliers_temp.obs)
    thisform.Suppliers.column1.Check2.valid
    select supplier_temp
    go top
    replace supplier_temp.control with 3
    locate for supplier_temp.control = 3
      REPLACE supplier.control WITH supplier_temp.control for supplier.id = supplier_temp.id IN  supplier
    Thisform.Suppliers.refresh
    thisform.Suppliers.setfocus()
    thisform.refresh
  endif
endif
```

The grid is not refresh despite having in the init and in the buttons the commands Thisform.Suppliers.refresh,thisform.Suppliers.setfocus() and
thisform.refresh. When the form is closed and reopened, the grid is refreshed

Comment: You've gotten lots of help with this in other forums. Please follow that advice and, if you still have issues, update this question with the changes and say you've done so.

Answer (score 0):

&& reset the grid control because init() executed twice

Thisform.Suppliers.RecordSource = ""

CREATE cursor supplier_temp from array structure

Thisform.Suppliers.RecordSource = "supplier_temp"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).